# Find an item from collection based on the minimum value of a property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following objects defined:

```
public class MyGroup
{
    public MyItem[] Items;
}

public class MyItem
{
    public int Val;
}
```

Say I have a list as List where each MyGroup object contains a varying number of MyItems; which in turn contains a varying value for Val.

How can I find the subset of MyGroup objects that contains the lowest Val across all MyGroup objects.

E.g:
If I define the list with following values

- **MyGroup1** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 1, 5 and
  7
- **MyGroup2** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 3 and,
  8
- **MyGroup3** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 2, 4,
  5 and, 7

Then the returned value will be **MyGroup1** (as a single item list) because it contains the value 1 which is the lowest across all values.

However, if there are multiple values with the lowest value like:

- **MyGroup1** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 1, 5 and 7
- **MyGroup2** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 3 and, 8
- **MyGroup3** contains a MyItem for each of the following values: 1, 4, 5 and, 7

Then it will return **MyGroup1** and **MyGroup3** in a list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int lowestValue = groups.SelectMany(group => group.Items)
                  .Min(item => item.Val);

IEnumerable<MyGroup> result = groups.Where(group => 
    group.Items.Select(item => item.Val).Contains(lowestValue));
```

This will be a two pass algorithm.  If you were suitably motivated you could do it in a single pass by keeping track of all of the items containing the min value while searching for that min value.

Comment: This is perfect. The two pass method is actually better than a big single statement as it makes it a bit more readable. Thanks.

Comment: A two-pass approach has an obvious race condition--this will not work at all if the value changes in real time. See my answer for a snippet that does this in one pass. (Obviously it's not guaranteed to be accurate if the values are changing each millisecond, but it won't just return null in that case.)

Comment: @piojo It's *impossible* to perform this operation if the underlying sequence is being mutated in another thread.  If the collection is accessible to other threads (something that's not mentioned at all as a requirement, I might add) then the solution would be to synchronize access to the collection and not allow any of those other threads to access it while this thread is performing this query.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I wasn't talking about threads. Some properties may change when you query them. Others may change as a result of time passing. Either way, it seems silly for the algorithm to break when a property changes value. For instance, if an object's position is not guaranteed to be the same each time it's queried, your function will fail to return anything for a "Get closest to point X" query. You might point out that that's a silly example, but why make the algorithm fail for such a preventable reason? (And note that it's not even guaranteed to always fail in this case.)

Comment: @piojo The question very specifically says that it has a `List`.  A `List` is not going to be mutated by the query shown, nor will it potentially return different results on each iteration.  Were the underlying `IEnumerable` to be something like a generator object, something that causes side effects when being queried, etc. then it's possible for iterating it multiple times to be a concern, but this is not one of those situations.

Comment: @Servy You're correct that it works fine for his example. (Not because it's a list, but because the objects he defined contain ints, rather than methods or properties.) My point is, why use code that only works in this one scenario? Brevity is the answer that comes to mind, particularly if you think you won't need to use this type of logic in the future.

Comment: @piojo Why did I not add features not required by the requirements?  Because they're not a part of the requirements.  If the question required the solution to only iterate the source sequence once, I'd have added it.  Supporting unnecessary features is expending effort unnecessarily.

Comment: @Servy I see your point. I thought the more robust code was in fact less effort, but that may be a result of the type of development I've been doing lately.

Comment: @piojo If one already had a `MinBy` implementation written, then re-using it here is likely to be simpler than doing this.  Writing an implementation of such a method when you don't have one, and explaining both the method, it's purpose, its implementation, and usage, in an answer, is simply something that I apparently didn't consider worth the effort when I wrote this answer 3 years ago.

Comment: @Servy Sure, that makes sense. I ended up on this page looking for the algorithm because I needed it, so I'm posting from the "this is what I used" perspective, rather than strictly answering a question. Indeed, my only real purpose is to make that small snippet available frmoreom search-engine results. Sorry if I came across as critical, I didn't mean it in an unfriendly way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var myGroup1 = new MyGroup();
    myGroup1.Items = Enumerable.Range (1,3).Select (x=> new MyItem {Val=x}).ToArray();
    var myGroup2 = new MyGroup();
    myGroup2.Items = Enumerable.Range (1,4).Select (x=> new MyItem {Val=x}).ToArray();
    var myGroup3 = new MyGroup();
    myGroup3.Items = Enumerable.Range (3,5).Select (x=> new MyItem {Val=x}).ToArray();


    var groupList = new List<MyGroup>();
    groupList.Add(myGroup1);
    groupList.Add(myGroup2);
    groupList.Add(myGroup3);

    var filterGroups = groupList.Select ( x=>new {Group=x, Min=x.Items.Select( y=> y.Val).Min()}).GroupBy (x=>x.Min).OrderBy (x=>x.Key).Take(1).SelectMany (x=> x).Select (x=>x.Group);
```

Last query is very large, because of nested data structure.

Following is explanation

`groupList`  //List of MyGroup
`.Select ( x=>new {Group=x, Min=x.Items.Select( y=> y.Val).Min()})` // List of Group, and Min value

`.GroupBy (x=>x.Min).OrderBy (x=>x.Key)` Group by minimum value and sort
`.Take(1)`// Take first item
`.SelectMany (x=> x)` //(List of MyGroups for minimum value)
`.Select (x=>x.Group)`;  // Select only MyGroups, ignore the Key

Answer (score 0):

```
   var query = from gr in myGroups
               where gr.Items.Any(x => x.Val ==
                 (from g in myGroups
                  from i in g.Items
                  orderby i.Val
                  select i.Val).FirstOrDefault())
               select gr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code snippet I just wrote for this. It's an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>`, and it returns a minimum element based on a "sort" function (without actually doing a sort, or performing two passes, and without the race condition that happens when you do two passes).

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the minimum element, based on some property, like a distance or a price.
/// </summary>
static public T MinElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, System.Func<T, float> selector)
{
    T ret = default(T);
    float minValue = float.MaxValue;
    foreach (T elem in list)
    {
        float value = selector(elem);
        if (value <= minValue)
        {
            ret = elem;
            minValue = value;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your Linq query: .FirstOrDefault(); and you get only one value.